# Как получить данные о видео Youtube аяксом после обновления API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Пытался так:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=_bWeZuPUZRA‌​&key=AIzaSyCRDrvUf4V4IjumKoo5woctjWw_scJoJ74
```

Дает Bad Requst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш url, с подстановкой другого ключа и вырезания невидимого юникодового мусора между `ZRA` и `&key` , выдает вполне нормальный результат:

[`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=_bWeZuPUZRA&key=AIzaSyDJz3xKLywmis4k-GxCigLzvhBuc8BHa6I`](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=_bWeZuPUZRA&key=AIzaSyDJz3xKLywmis4k-GxCigLzvhBuc8BHa6I)

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/u_ANb0gbXz0_uU5DHO4CxFlAV3E\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/b1x_YkeRGElE_k5_2EH6NJ6i148\"",
   "id": "_bWeZuPUZRA",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT3M53S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

мусор можно заметить если сначала вставить вашу ссылку в адресную строку, потом скопировать, и еще раз вставить - появляется `id=_bWeZuPUZRA%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B&key` вместо `id=_bWeZuPUZRA&key`. Или по задержке курсора при переходе между символами `A&`. Проверяйте код, которым вы строите ссылку - в нем явно глюк.

Comment: Я пробовал и для другого ID - та же история. В релизе новой версии указано - что сменился API - до этого все работало

Comment: По Вашему примеру не парсится инфо о видео

Comment: @Jony - что значит "не парсится"? JSON же нормальный приходит. что вам мешает его распарсить?

Comment: @Jony у вас ссылка из моего ответа просто в бразуере открывается? что выдает?

Comment: @PashaPash http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bWeZuPUZRA вот это отдаёт, а вам что нужно?

Comment: @ПавелДурa мне ничего не нужно, у меня все отлично работает. у задавшего вопрос глючит, потому что у него 3 невидимых символа в url вписаны, и он получает ` "items": []`.